# When I using `go install`, it returns not a main package

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

I used `import "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"` in my code. The environment is `go1.17.2 Windows AMD64`. I executed `go install github.com/go-redis/redis/v8@latest`, but the result is `package github.com/go-redis/redis/v8 is not a main package`. What's wrong of my operations or the config of environment. `go env GO111MODULE=on`.

And when I execute `go run main.go`, it shows `cannot find package` at the line of import `github.com/go-redis/redis/v8`.

Content in `go.mod`, (with simple `go mod init` & `go mod tidy`):

```
module ...
go 1.17

require github.com/go-redis/redis/v8 v8.11.4

require (
    github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2 v2.1.2 // indirect
    github.com/dgryski/go-rendezvous v0.0.0-20200823014737-9f7001d12a5f // indirect
)
```

Comment: What is the content of your `go.mod`?

Comment: i think you want go mot init and go get instead of go install

Answer (score 1):

The module name of your `go.mod` is invalid. I try the similar module name in my environment and compile with `go build`, it reports:

```
$ go build
go: malformed module path "...": invalid path element "..."
```

Try a name like:

```
module tempredis
go 1.17

require github.com/go-redis/redis/v8 v8.11.4
```

Or create the module with command `go mod init tempredis` then add a dependency of `github.com/go-redis/redis/v8`.

Refer to [document](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules).

Comment: Actually, I created `go.mod` file with command `go mod init` and `go mod tidy` already. Can you help me check the content in `go.mod` file in my question? Thanks a lot. And when I execute `go build` it reports `cannot find package` as well.

Comment: @Eternally_Ascend The answer have been updated. Where is your `go.mod`? Is it in the same directory with `main.go`? Do you execute `go build` in the same directory path? Maybe after `go mod init` you need to `go get github.com/go-redis/redis/v8` manually.

Answer (score 1):

I use `import "github.com/go-redis/redis"`, and restart the process (include `go mod init`, `go mod tidy`, `go install`), it shows right result finally. But the version of go redis changes to `v6.15.9+incompatible` in `go.mod` file automatedly.